# what port tomcat7 use? how do I set AWS Security group?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, tomcat7

I run a tomcat7 in ubuntu in aws. not use apache.
and my site use default tomcat port 8080.

I don't want to open port except 8080 so I'm setting in aws security group.
inbound 
8080 TCP anywhere
and outbound allTraffic.

but I try to rest call to

```
http://my_aws_ip:8080/test.do
```

but it doesn't work.

What should I open the port?
Does tomcat7 use a some port?

Comment: Did you install tomcat7 with apt-get?  Is it running (`sudo service tomcat7 status`)?

Comment: yes run nomal when i add all Traffic security group it works.

Comment: Double check your security groups.  If allowing all traffic from everywhere works with that URL then just allowing tcp/8080 inbound for everywhere should also work.

Comment: and i use mysql 3306 port. and i add security group 3306 but still dosen't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat uses whatever port or ports and protocols you configure it to use.  By default it listens for HTTP requests on tcp/8080, AJP requests on tcp/8009, and service management requests on tcp/8005.

This is configured in **Connector** elements in **$CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml**:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

You should reconfigure Tomcat to listen on standard ports like tcp/80 for HTTP and tcp/443 for HTTPS.  Non-standard ports are a ready indication of a novice deployment.

The AWS Security Group should be configured to allow HTTP, HTTPS, pr both depending on your need.  I highly recommend using HTTPS unless the information being transferred is public domain or has no value.

You can check what ports Tomcat is using on your EC2 instance with `netstat -anpt`.  It will show all active and listen ports and the programs that have bound them (including java or tomcat for your Tomcat ports).

Unless you really need root access to the OS, you might want to consider using [Amazon Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html) as it manages all that cruft for you.

Comment: thanks but i want to know why this happen. and i register all port 8080, 8009, 8005 in server.xml but it didn't work.

Comment: If you run `sudo netstat -anpt | grep LISTEN`  on the Ubuntu EC2 what output do you get?

Comment: tcp  0.0.0.0:3690   LISTEN 20737/svnserve  
tcp  0.0.0.0:3306   LISTEN 25669/mysqld    
tcp6 :::8080        LISTEN 31150/java      
tcp6 :::49152       LISTEN 31150/java      
tcp6 :::49154       LISTEN 31150/java      
tcp6 :::49155       LISTEN 31150/java      
tcp6 127.0.0.1:8005 LISTEN 31150/java      
tcp6 :::8009        LISTEN 31150/java

Comment: Possibly, but unlikely related to IPv6. Try adding this to CATALINA_OPTS `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.  Does `curl http://localhost:8080/test.do` work as expected when run on the EC2 instance?